# AngularJS Unit testing $location

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, location

I am pretty new at unit testing and AngularJS and I have some issue that I can't fix. One of my test is not working. I am trying to initiate a location.path() in my test by affecting a value, but in my controller, location.path() still have a undefined value.

Here is my controler:

```
angular.module('...')
.controller('SignUpCtrl', ['$location', function ($location) {

    // Retrieve type of user
    var userType = $location.path().substr(9);
    if(userType == 'member'){
        userType = 'user';
    }

    console.log($location.path());
    console.log(userType);

    $scope.uType = userType;  ]);
```

And here is my test module:

```
describe('Controller: SignUpCtrl', function () {

// load the controller's module
beforeEach(module('...'));

var SignUpCtrl,
    scope,
    mockBackend,
    environments,
    location,
    store;

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend,$location,_Environments_) {
    environments = _Environments_;
    mockBackend = $httpBackend;
    location = $location;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    SignUpCtrl = $controller('SignUpCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $location: location
    });
}));

it('should come from the right location', function(){
    location.path('/sign-up/member');
    expect(location.path()).toBe('/sign-up/member');

    expect(scope.uType).toBe('user'); //Do not work
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use unit testing to do something that can only really be achieved using End-to-End (or E2E) testing.  Unit testing in AngularJS is designed to test the javascript within a given module or sub-module (such as a `service`, `factory`, `directive`, etc).  However, things like page navigation or browser location really need to be tested in an end-to-end testing environment.

Because of that, your $location object won't have all the normal methods (like `path`, `url`, etc).  The $location object ends up simply being a "mock" of the actual $location object that you'd get in your module.  So, you just need to move your test case for `it('should come from the right location', function(){ ... })` to an end-to-end test and then continue on with your other module-specific unit tests.  After you do that, you can simplify the $controller by only grabbing the `$scope` variable, as in the following:

```
scope = $rootScope.new();
SignUpCtrl = $controller('SignUpCtrl', {$scope: scope});
```

The guide for E2E testing can be found at [this link](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing).  It walks you through how to write good E2E tests.  There is a really great framework available for doing angular E2E tests called Protractor.  The info for that is at [this link](https://github.com/angular/protractor).  Protractor will soon (in 1.2) replace Karma as a better way to handle E2E testing.

Comment: Thank you for response I gonna have a look at E2E testing as it is still pretty confuse for me on what to test in unit testing and what in E2E...